# WP_Query returning everything BUT post content

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm simply trying to show the content of posts in category 7 on a template page. I'm using the following on the template page:

```
<?php 
  $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=7');
  while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
echo get_the_title();
endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This code is ONLY returning the title of posts in category 7, and is not outputting the actual post content. I added the get_the_title() line only to see if the query was actually querying the posts. Since it returned the title as expected, I assume it is querying the posts as it should. But why no content?? This is currently a local site so I cannot provide a link. Is anything glaringly missing in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you need to add `the_content();` in the query to make the post content visible?

Comment: UGH... I knew it was something simple. Thanks much!

Comment: Also if you just put the_title(); instead of get_the_title();, you don't need the echo command. get_the_title(); is when you want to use it in your code, the_title(); is when you put to put it out on the page. Same goes for content, meta data etc. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title
Also, just as a note, it's customary to mark an answer as correct (tick symbol of the left of the answer) if the commenter answered your question correctly :)